# Can I write 'Ecce Esse!'?

Tags: translation-check, english-to-latin-translation, esse

Is '*ecce esse!*' acceptable Latin for 'Lo, to be!'?

I've tried looking online for answers, but I've not found anything definitive either confirming or disconfirming that it is, though I do not have experience in this kind of research.

Comment: FWIW, _esse_ also means _being_ in a philosophical sense, as in _human being_, since at least medieval Latin. So _ecce esse_ can also be translated as _behold the being_

Comment: @Rafael In that sense I would expect the participle *ens*. Comparing that and *esse* might make an interesting new question...

Comment: _Ens_ works as _being_ as well. My metaphysics are a bit rusty now. You are right in that _a being_ is _ens_, but I think _the being_ (~existence) is esse. St. Thomas Aquinas defines God as _ipsum esse subsistens_. And there is also _actus essendi_, the act of being. For me all the three are _ser_ in Spanish. Maybe that is the source of my mixing up the meanings

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can.
In Latin you can always write *ecce* and a noun, as in *ecce homo*.
The infinitive of a verb (such as *esse*) can be used as a noun.
For oblique cases you would have to consider the gerund, but it is not needed here.

The phrase *ecce esse* will be a little difficult to parse, just as "lo, to be" is.
It is a compact and unusual expression, but I see nothing ungrammatical about it.

Whether *ecce esse* is the best phrase for your purpose depends on context.
As a translation of "lo, to be" without further context it is fine.
In more specific situations there can be better ways to put it.